# Minimum work separating gas from a reservoir

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics

I have a problem asking me the minimum work required to separate a mole of oxygen from a reservoir which is 20% oxygen.

So the minimum work implies we are looking at a reversible change. So we could think about the maximum work done when we add a mole of gas to the reservoir.

Intuitively I think that the problem will revolve about the fact that the one mole of oxygen alone will have a different entropy to the mole in the mixture. However I get stuck as the problem is based in a constant T, constant P environment.

$$dA = dU - T_{R}dS + p_{R}dV - \sum_{i}\mu_{R,i}dN_{i} $$
$$dA = (T - T_{R})dS - (p-p_{R})dV - \sum_{i}(\mu_{i}-\mu_{R,i})dN_{i}$$

Therefore as $(T - T_{R})=0$ and $(p-p_{R})=0$ we are left with:

$$dA = - \sum_{i}(\mu_{i}-\mu_{R,i})dN_{i}$$

Therefore the work should be $(\mu_{O_{2}}-\mu_{R,O_{2}})$ for one mole but I don't think I have enough information/know how to calculate the chemical potentials

Comment: Can you please state the problem exactly?

Comment: @ChesterMiller The moderators typically don't accept direct questions so I tried to explain my reasoning. but the problem is "What is the minimum work required to extract 1 mole of pure $O_2$ from a large volume of air at the same temperature and pressure, if air is regarded as being composed of 1 volume of $O_2$ mixed with 4 volumes of $N_2$?"

Comment: For an ideal gas, $\mu=\mu^0(T)+RT\ln {p}$ where p is the partial pressure in atm, and $\mu^0(T)$ is the chemical potential at temperature T and 1 atm.

Comment: I would have solved this much differently.

Comment: I got an answer that matched the numerical value given as a hint, I used the nernst equation as you suggested. I also get the same result from using $d\mu_{O_2}=vdp_{O_2}-sdT$ but thats ends up being simply the adjustment in the nernst equation given constant T. How would you have done it?

Comment: I would have connected a cylinder with a piston to the large chamber, with a semipermeable membrane in between.  I would have pushed a second piston into the large chamber to force one mole of oxygen through the semipermeable membrane while at the same time allowing the piston in the small chamber to move so that the volume in the small cylinder increased at constant pressure while the volume in the large chamber decreased at constant pressure.  The pressure in the large chamber would be P and the pressure in the small chamber would be P/5.  (continued in next comment)

Comment: But, the volume change in the large chamber would be $\Delta V$, while the volume injected into the small cylinder would be $5\Delta V$.  So the net work needed to remove the mole of gas from the large chamber and inject it into the small chamber would be zero.  I would then block off the semipermeable membrane (semipermeable to oxygen), and compress the 1 mole of oxygen in the cylinder isothermally from P/5 to P.